# Basic Java exception handling

Tags: java, concurrency

Considering following code

```
class work {
    do_something() {
        try {
            // so something
        } catch (Throwable t) {/* operation alpha */
        }//
    }
}

class thread_instance implements Runnable {
    work w;

    public void run() {
        try {
            w.do_something();
        } catch (Throwable t) {/* operation beta */
        }//
    }
}
```

Later I want to create a thread(`thread_instance`) and might cancel it if some conditions appear, and I would give signal to `thread_instance` in order to reach `operation beta`.

```
class call_thread {
    static public void main(String...main){
          Thread tx=new Thread(new thread_instance());
          tx.start();
          //....
          if(<<some condition>>){tx.stop();} //tries to tell thread_instance about stop command
         }
}
```

But as `word#do_something(void)` is called by `thread_instance` and ables to catch the any exception, the operation beta won't called anyway.

**Question:**

How may I figure out if there was an exception/error by `thread_instance#run(void)` method, while the exception has catched by inner call (`word#do_something(void)`)? and suppose the inner call will not throws the exception for higher level.

Comment: You could always throw the exception further by putting `throw t;` in your catch clause. Alternatively you could save the information that an exception or error occurred, say in a boolean. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Throw an exception in do_something catch Block.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, assume I cannot do this.

Comment: @blalasaadri tried, any exception type I throw by `stop()` will trigger the operation alpha since all of them inherited by `Throwable`

Comment: thats a strange assumption

Comment: check this thread [Waiting for condition in Java][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350737/waiting-for-condition-in-java

Comment: @yogx Why so strange? I'm developing a thread pool, and I will give it to the clients, how would I force the developers to do not catch throwable or x?

Comment: Catching `Throwable` is often a sign of bad design; you should generally be more specific. However, if you really want to act like that you could define your own `ThreadPoolException` which takes a `Throwable` as a constructor argument and throw that in `do_something`. Then in the `thread_instance` you catch `ThreadPoolException`s *before* you catch all other `Throwable`s and then throw that on.

Comment: if you want to execute a certain block of code on thread stop, then, extend Thread class, override stop api, call super.stop() and then call your beta code. Also call the beta code api from catch of run too.

Comment: @yogx not bad idea, but doesn't cover the problem, because there would be too much of `thread_instance` and different business for operation beta

Comment: @blalasaadri I know dear, but what if the `work#do_something()` catch it? I don't have any idea and access to work. `thread_instance` is all the thing I can manage, and I would get the any stop/interrupt signal even if it's catched by inner level.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. You can't change `work#do_something()` but only stuff in `thread_instance`? And you want to detect whether an exception was thrown in `work#do_something()` which wasn't passed on to `thread_instance#run()`? If so, I don't think it can be done.

Comment: @blalasaadri exactly, and it sounds very bad! so you're telling me it's impossible?

Comment: I don't know. It may be possible using interceptors, but I'm not familiar enough with that technology to say for sure. You can find out about them here though: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

public class ThreadExceptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                throw new NullPointerException();//Where your exception will be thrown
            }
        };
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {//Creates a default handler for the thread
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                arg1.printStackTrace();//Do whatever you want with the exception here
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help dear, but didn't help buddy. the run will call another method catches any exception/error. and because there is a try/catch block did catch the exception, the `uncaughtException(arg0:Thread,arg1:Throwable)` will not be invoked anyway. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You do not have to place the try/catch block. Also, you can just rethrow the exception with throw e; So: `try{ something that throws error}catch(Throwable e){throw e;} You may just put a throw new NullPointerException(); with no try/catch and the compiler will be happy.

Comment: I personaly use this but inseead, I use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to catch any errors that occur in my game and send them to me via email. All seamlessly.